# Suppose that $A$ is a square matrix of order $n$ over $\mathbb{R}$. If $A$ and $A^T$ are linearity dependent, what can we say about the nature of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is a square matrix of order $n$ over $\mathbb{R}$. If $A$ and $A^T$ are linearity dependent, what can we say about the nature of $A$, that is, can we say that $A$ is either symmetric or skew-symmetric?

My approach: Since $A$ and $A^T$ are linearity dependent, so there exists scalars $\alpha,\beta$, not all zero so that $\alpha A+\beta A^T=0$. Suppose that $\alpha\neq0$. Then $A=-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}A^T$. I know that $A,A^T$ have the same characteristic polynomial. From this can we conclude that $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\pm 1$?

Answer (score 2):

If $A\ne0$, then, since $A$ and $A^T$ are linearly dependent, $A^T=\lambda A$, for some scalar $\lambda$. So, if $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$, then, for each $i$ and each $j$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $a_{ji}=\lambda a_{ij}$. But then, if $a_{ij}\ne0$, since $a_{ij}=\lambda a_{ji}=\lambda^2 a_{ij}$, $\lambda^2=1$, and therefore $\lambda=\pm1$. So, either $A^T=A$ (that is, $A$ is symmetric) or $A^T=-A$ (that is, $A$ is anti-symmetric). Of course, if $A=0$, then $A$ is both symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

If $A\ne [0] $, then

$aA+bA^T=[0] \tag 1$

$(aA+bA^T)^T=aA^T+bA=[0] \implies A^T=-b/a A$

So by $(1): [0] =aA+bA^T=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a} A\implies a^2=b^2\implies \frac ba=\pm1$